# JUnit 4.11 get test result in @After

Tags: java, junit, junit4

Is there any way I can get the test result in the teardown (`@After`) method? I'd like to do clean up after the tests depending on the result.

Could not find much details about `@After` in the junit docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closest thing to what you're asking for would probably be the [TestWatcher](http://junit.org/javadoc/latest/org/junit/rules/TestWatcher.html) rule. That won't give you access to a returned result or anything, but you can use it (or create your own [TestRule](http://junit.org/javadoc/latest/org/junit/rules/TestRule.html) and combined with the Description object, you could annotate your methods differently to indicate what sort of clean-up is necessary.

Comment: Since `testwatcher` implements `succeeded` and `failed` methods, this will tell you what the test result is - so IMO this should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you use TestNG, it is a standard function, your @After method can look like this:

```
@AfterTest
public void cleanUp( ITestResult result ) {
    boolean success = result.isSuccess();
    ....
```

Comment: Yes, that's what im looking for. Seems like junit does not provide this sort of feature. (+1)

Comment: That's right.   The TestNG documentation is not really clear on this but all of the @Configuration methods can accept built-in optional arguments, such as what you see above, and so you can do some pretty amazing things in different parts of the test lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no standard possibility (I'm pretty sure there was no possibility in JUnit 3.x), you can just

write a Listener,

push the Listener-events to a static Collection,

and gather them from your @After- Method.

Answer (score 0):

Why not set the result of a test in a class member and then act on it in the @After method?

```
public enum TestResult {
    ...
}

public class TestClass {

    private TestResult result;
     ...
    @Test
    public void aTest() {
    // set up test
    // call class under test
    // assert something and set result based upon outcome
    this.result = ...; 
    }
    ...
   @After
    public void teardown() {
     // clean up based upon this.result
    }
}
```

I suspect you would not have too many different results and a finite set will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

I am using something alike JamesB suggested. You might get to the point where you have to add timeouts to the tests, then =>>

"setting the result of a test in a class member and then act on it in the @After method" would not always work if you have more than 1 assert. That's is my problem today, when i have testCaces that timeout, but my afterClass is assuming everything went smooth because the most recent assert has passed..