# Get JUNIT result from a test to post its result in testrail

Tags: java, selenium, junit, testrail

i am new to all of this coding experience. i have been a manual qa for several years and now i am starting to get my hands on selenium

i have worked out a very simple test case to submit a registration form, and i would like to get the result for that test case and post it on my testing tool "Test Rail". i have been doing it with soapui while testing endpoints so i know how to do it but not how to associate the result of the test case to trigger the post condition.

now i am using selenium with eclipse and Junit and this is my simple code:

```
package com.example.tests;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.junit.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class createLead {
private WebDriver driver;
private Select dropdown;

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception { 
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Agustin Barcia\\driver\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }

  @Test
  public void testUntitledTestCase() throws Exception {
    driver.get("www.randomform.com");    
    driver.findElement(By.id("firstname-input")).sendKeys("agustin");
    driver.findElement(By.id("lastname-input")).sendKeys("placement");
    driver.findElement(By.id("emailaddress-input")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("emailaddress-input")).sendKeys("random@email.com");
    driver.findElement(By.id("country-select"));
    dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("country-select")));
    dropdown.selectByValue("ar");
    driver.findElement(By.id("state-select"));
    dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("state-select")));
    dropdown.selectByValue("178");
    driver.findElement(By.id("city-select"));
    dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("city-select")));
    dropdown.selectByValue("245");
    driver.findElement(By.id("submit-button")).click();    
    } 
}
```

When i run this code in Junit the window shows "Success" and the registration is made.

Well now i have the code to post the resul in testrail, i would like to make a conditional if, the test case above returns "success" post in testrail a testcase ok, and if the test case returns "failure" post in test rail the test case failed.  i know how to post the result but not how to obtain the "success" or "Fail" from the test run

any help?

Comment: You should check out JUnit's [TestWatchman/TestWatcher Rules](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Rules#testwatchmantestwatcher-rules)

Comment: @JakubCh. thanks! ihave checked testwachman, but since i am not a developer i dont wheater if a have to create a new class for the rules or justa add up the portion code to my test class above

Comment: _i dont wheater if a have to create a new class for the rules or justa add up the portion code to my test class above_ - it depends on you. If you'd like to reuse the rule for many test classes/suites then you should provide a new class for the rule (to avoid code duplication). Otherwise it can stay within `createLead` class (e.g. if you do this just to learn stuff or if it's a single case of posting the result to testrail)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JUnit 4.11 get test result in @After](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22773590/junit-4-11-get-test-result-in-after)

Answer (score 0):

I have done this -

"i would like to make a conditional if, the test case above returns "success" post in testrail a testcase ok, and if the test case returns "failure" post in test rail the test case failed.i know how to post the result but **not how to obtain the "success" or "Fail" from the test run**"

by making a reporting class which implements ITTestListner and captures the result of test case as below:-

```
 public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult tr) {

System.out.println("onTestSuccess");

String screenshotPath = ".//" + screenshotName + ".png";
File screenshotTRPath = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/Reports/" + 
     screenshotName + ".png");

System.out.println("screenshotPath-->" + screenshotPath);
System.out.println("screenshotTRPath-->" + screenshotTRPath.toString());
///TestRail API
try {
    addResultForTestCase(currentTestCaseId, TEST_CASE_PASSED_STATUS, 
 screenshotTRPath.toString());
} catch (IOException | APIException | ParseException e) {  e.printStackTrace();

}
```